Can the chunk size or IMFSample of the IMFSourceReader:: OnReadSample method be modified?
I use Flutter to call the record package and start the recording stream on Windows.
The audio format I set is 16bit PCM, 48000HZ, signal channel.
The source code in the package uses IMFSourceReader, and after executing ReadSample, OnReadSample is immediately called. After OnReadSample responds, send audio data to Flutter. But the duration of each data block is 50ms. When I reduced the sampling rate, the size of the data block changed, but the duration remained 50ms. Is there any way to increase the frequency of calling OnReadSample? Or can the duration of the data block be reduced to 10ms? Or are there other Windows APIs that can achieve low latency recording streams?
Thank you very much for your help
hr = m_pReader->ReadSample((DWORD)MF_SOURCE_READER_FIRST_AUDIO_STREAM,
                0,
                NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL
            );

if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {
            hr = pMediaType->SetGUID(MF_MT_MAJOR_TYPE, MFMediaType_Audio);
        }
        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {
            hr = pMediaType->SetGUID(MF_MT_SUBTYPE, MFAudioFormat_PCM);
        }
        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {
            hr = pMediaType->SetUINT32(MF_MT_AUDIO_BITS_PER_SAMPLE, 16);
        }
        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {
            hr = pMediaType->SetUINT32(MF_MT_AUDIO_SAMPLES_PER_SECOND, m_pConfig->sampleRate);
        }
        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {
            hr = pMediaType->SetUINT32(MF_MT_AUDIO_BLOCK_ALIGNMENT, 2);
        }
        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {
            hr = pMediaType->SetUINT32(MF_MT_AUDIO_SAMPLES_PER_BLOCK, 480);
        }
        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {
            hr = pMediaType->SetUINT32(MF_MT_AUDIO_NUM_CHANNELS, m_pConfig->numChannels);
        }
        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {
            hr = pMediaType->SetUINT32(MF_MT_AVG_BITRATE, m_pConfig->bitRate);
        }
        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {
            *ppMediaType = pMediaType;
            (*ppMediaType)->AddRef();
        }

        SafeRelease(&pMediaType);

        return hr;
    }

I tried to add some parameters, such as MF_ST_AUDIO_SLOCK_ALIGNMENT, MF_SAUDIO_SAMPLES-PER-BLOCK, but it didn't work. I hope to reduce the recording buffer size to achieve more refined operations.
